# problems running a PHP script from command line

Tags: php

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. I've set up the environment variables... and i can do php -v and it'll show me the version. However, if i do php blah.php to run a php script i've written, the console returns with no errors and the script is not run? I know this script works, because i made it a long time ago when i first worked with PHP - however, i don't remember PHP or anything about it at the moment.

does it have something to do with SET PATH? I don't see a .bat file in the PHP folder though. Yet, it seems to be working fine when i run php -v... so confused...

Help? How do i run this script?

Comment: make sure you have errors enabled in your CLI config. Without any sort of output it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the -f option to execute a file

```
php -f blah.php
```

It may also be useful to read the help

```
php -h
```

Comment: I was too slow! While I was off figuring this out, you got it. :-)

Comment: hmm i've tried that.. but doesn't seem to want to run it... perhaps i've messed something else up.. thanks anyway +1

Comment: did you double check the path to blah? maybe `php -f /home/username/public_html/blah.php` or `php -f /home/username/blah.php` Just a guess since I work out of user folders a lot, maybe you do too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
php -f blah.php
```

From php -h

-f         Parse and execute <file>.